# Do braces in an if/else statement affect memory on the stack?

Tags: memory, memory-management, stack

Regardless of good or bad form, do curly braces in a single line if statement result in more memory on the stack being allocated when compared to single line if statements without the braces?

For example. Would this

```
if (foo) bar = baz;
```

use less memory than this

```
if (foo) { bar = baz; }
```

From my understanding the braces define a new scope for local variables. These are allocated on the stack. Single line if statements don't require braces but do they still result in the same implications on memory?

Comment: Why do you think that this could possibly make any difference ? The source code is equivalent, so the compiler will generate the same code for either case. If in doubt, compile both cases and look at the generated code.

Comment: The braces (and `(` pairs) only concern the compiler. Neither of them have anything to do with stack space or memory in runtime code.

Comment: Paul R, could you give me a quick run through of how I could go about looking at the compiled code from both of the examples above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you thinking about?

Speaking in general, the only possibility for additional memory usage I can think of in this case would be a sloppy compiler blindly using buffer overflow detection techniques (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection for examples), and it could be more likely in a debug build because optimizations are usually disabled in those cases.

A proper compiler in release builds would eliminate such code when it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr it depends.

It would depend on how the interpreter/compiler/other is implemented.

In C, in the case of `if (foo) bar = baz;`, a new scope is implied.

But could an `if` written with braces vs. without result in a different stack size at some point in the program? To best answer this question, consider a hypothetical language parser which accepts the following subset of grammar, denoted in Backus-Naur Form.

```
IF_AST ::= IF_TOKEN EXPRESSION_AST STATEMENT_AST | IF_TOKEN EXPRESSION_AST BLOCK_STATEMENT_AST
STATEMENT_LIST_AST ::= OPEN_BLOCK_TOKEN | STATEMENT_LIST_AST STATEMENT_AST
BLOCK_STATEMENT_AST ::= STATEMENT_LIST_AST CLOSE_BLOCK_TOKEN
```

In this case, `if (foo) bar = baz;` could resolve to an abstract syntax tree (AST) that looks something like this.

```
IF_AST
    EXPRESSION_AST
        ...
    STATEMENT_AST
        ...
```

Where `if (foo) { bar = baz; }` could resolve to something like this.

```
IF_AST
    EXPRESSION_AST
        ...
    BLOCK_STATEMENT_AST
        STATEMENT_LIST_AST
            STATEMENT_AST
                ...
```

From the perspective of our hypothetical parser, the difference in syntax can result in a different size stack. Depending on what is done with the resulting AST, it can also lead to a different internal representation of the program and even a different size memory footprint.

Compilers of today are typically heavily optimized, so it is very likely that the resulting programs would be the same. However, it is possible that your examples could yield different stack sizes during the construction of your program and in the resulting program itself.